# How to handle roles and scopes using oauth2 auth flow

Tags: security, authentication, authorization, oauth2

I'm using python and fastapi with oauth2 flow (just for clarification as the question isn't language specific).

I'm confused on how to implement scopes in an efficient and secure way. I was thinking of using roles and associating scopes to these roles, so when an user with determined role logs in, the API issues a token with the scopes assigned to that role. But i've been reading that implementing scopes in that way is not how they should be used and it's not clear for me which should be the correct implementation. It would be appreciated if anyone can shed some light.